# What is the difference between [ambiguity] and [ambiguous]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Both tags seem to have the same description:

> Ambiguity can refer to two related concepts: 'ambiguous calls' and 'ambiguous grammars'.

vs.

> An ambiguous call is a situation in which the compiler cannot deduce which version of a function or method to use from the given parameter types. This tag should not be confused with the [ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity) tag.

As for the "should not be confused with" part, disregarding ambiguous grammars how can I not confuse them if they are about the  same thing (ambiguous calls)?

Comment: I find those descriptions ambiguous.

Comment: @Louis Even though you had ambiguous in your comment it was without ambiguity..

Comment: They are the same in meaning. "This tag should not be confused with the ambiguity tag" is ambiguous. I propose to merge them.

Comment: As an expert in ambiguity I strongly kind of support maybe keeping both these tags

Comment: Let us disambiguate the ambiguous ambiguity tag!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they should be merged, and renamed. [ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous) should become [ambiguous-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous-calls), and an [ambiguous-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous-grammar) tag should be used. Both [ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity) and [ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous) are too ambiguous to be good tags. ;)

Answer (score -1):

**Ambiguity** is a noun and a concept. You can talk about ambiguity, you can describe ambiguity, you can even try to prevent it.

**Ambiguous** is an adjective, derived from the noun, describing something. Like, "that text is ambiguous".

When describing ambiguity, it helps if the description isn't ambiguous.

Comment: It seems like the OP understands is aware of the definitions of the terms but disambiguation between their usage as separate and individual tags.

Comment: @Spaceghost I think so too.