# Ambiguity of [ambiguous] and [ambiguous-call]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

There's previously been a discussion on [ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity) versus [ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous) that appears to [have resulted in yet more tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276568/1270789) that are just confusing everything even more than they were before. Can someone please synonymise a few of them to at least try to reduce the ambiguity?